# Access violation writing location while giving value to a struct

Tags: c++, struct, physics

I am trying to give a value to a 2D struct in a loop but i keep getting Access violation writing location error
My code is :

```
typedef struct {
int prtcls[10],numb;
} intpos;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

particle_t* particles;
intpos** points = new intpos*[(int)SCALE];
for (int i = 0; i < (int)SCALE; i++) {

    intpos* row = new intpos[(int)SCALE - 1];
    points[i] = row;
}
cudaMallocHost(&particles, sizeof(particle_t)*NUM_PARTICLES);
// Random initial positions / directions.
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++)
{
    particles[i].x =( (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * SCALE ;
    particles[i].y = ((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * SCALE;
    particles[i].phi = ((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 2 * 3.14;
    particles[i].flrx = floor(particles[i].x) ;
    particles[i].flry = floor(particles[i].y) ;
    int fx = particles[i].flrx;
    int fy = particles[i].flry;
    points[fx][fy].numb += 1;
    int curn = points[fx][fy].numb;
    points[fx][fy].prtcls[curn] = i;
}
```

and full error is :
0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000001DEA3C7836C.

Comment: `operator new` suggests you are writing a C++ code, but everything else looks like C; Then you allocate NUM_PARTICLES items, but iterating over magic number of 18432. So, no idea, try to clean it a bit, [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.

Comment: While `cudaMallocHost` suggests it's a C++ CUDA program, the code you show runs purely on the CPU. Use a normal debugger or valgrind or sanitizers to find the error. It's 99.99% probability that you access some arrays, `particles` or `points`, outside their boundaries. Also, compiling the code in Debug mode and running it under a debugger will give you the exact line number where your program segfalults.

Comment: Hi . thank you for your answer . it's in this line : points[fx][fy].prtcls[curn] = i; . also it's not full code in rest of the code i use cuda for my calculations .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What line? If you're using the GNU tools, gdb and a stack trace will tell you what line is crashing.

I suspect it's one of these lines:

```
particles[i].x =( (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * SCALE ;
points[fx][fy].numb += 1;
points[fx][fy].prtcls[curn] = i;
```

Are you absolutely sure all those array index values are in range?

Comment: Hi . thank you for your answer . it's in this line  : points[fx][fy].prtcls[curn] = i; . also i checked it goes well for 10 or 20 values well but when it gets to some index (which are in range of array) it shows me this message .

Comment: Well, I don't have a clue what this code is actually trying to do, but that suggests that curn is well out of range.

Comment: Thank you sir i solved it . I gave 0 to all of points[fx][fy].numb and it fixed it . apparently without doing it values were some negative numbers so they were out of the range.